# Rationale for taking second derivative in least squares estimation?

Tags: regression, self-study, least-squares

I am reading DeGroot and he talks about how to derive the b0 and b1 coefficients using LS estimation.  I understand everything except the last part where he talks about taking the second derivative of the cost function.  What is the rationale for doing this?  Is this to check if we are at minimum or maximum or is there more to it than that?  I thought the cost function is convex.

[image]

Comment: It’s to prove that the spot you’ve found is indeed a minimum.

Comment: As opposed to...it being a maximum?

Comment: Or a saddle point...just any other point that has zero gradient but isn’t the minimum

Comment: @confused: There's a theorem that says that, if you find a point , $\beta^{*}$, of a function where the gradient of the function equals zero, then,  if the hessian of the function is positive definite at that point $\beta^{*}$,  then $\beta^{*}$ is a global minimum. In your case, the  "hessian" is just the second derivatives ( and the partials ) of $\beta_{0}$ and $\beta_1$

Comment: Wow, thanks did not know that!  Did not know there's a way to find a global minimum just by looking at the hessian.  I'm guessing that's a pro of finding analytical results as opposed to doing something numerical like gradient descent cuz I recall there's a lot of times when we are unable to find a global minimum.

Comment: In general it doesn't guarantee that you find a global minimum, but here there is only one solution to the normal equations and it's a minimum, so it does have to be *the* minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Recall from single-variable calculus that th derivative of a function being zero does not guarantee that point to be a minimum. Indeed, the point could be a maximum (e.g., $f(x)=-x^2$) or neither a maximum nor a minimum (e.g., $f(x)=x^3$). The second derivative shows us if the point is a minimum or not.

There is similar logic in multivariable calculus related to the second and mixed partial derivatives in the Hessian matrix.

Therefore, just because we found a point where the loss function has a derivative of zero does not mean that the point must be a minimum. Checking the higher-order derivatives in the Hessian matrix confirms that the point is indeed the desired minimum.

Answer (score 0):

There are first and second order conditions of minimum of the function at a point $x$:
$$F.O.C.: f'(x)=0\\S.O.C.: f''(x)>0$$
It's in basic calculus curriculum in high schools.

Comment: I believe the situation is subtler than this: the case of deficient-rank design matrices is one where the second derivative is only positive *semi* definite--and that does not assure a minimum has been reached.